# How to take data from multiple nodes in a xml file use them in different text file using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a sample xml file which is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd">
<article article-type="proceedings" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
<front>
<journal-meta>
<journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id"/>
<journal-title-group>
<journal-title>Eleventh International Conference on Correlation Optics</journal-title>
</journal-title-group>
<issn pub-type="epub">0277-786X</issn>
<publisher>
<publisher-name>SPIE</publisher-name>
</publisher>
</journal-meta>
<article-meta>
<article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.236/12.205210</article-id>
<title-group>
<article-title>So you think you can dance?</article-title>
</title-group>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Cena</surname>
<given-names>John</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a1"><sup>a</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="yes">
<name>
<surname>Pal</surname>
<given-names>G.S.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a2"><sup>b</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<aff id="a1"><label><sup>a</sup></label>CNRS, France</aff>
<aff id="a2"><label><sup>b</sup></label>MIT, USA</aff>
</contrib-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="S1">
<label>1.</label>
<p>Today is your lucky day</p>
</sec>
<sec id="S2">
<label>2.</label>
<p>Today is not so lucky</p>
</sec>
</body>
</article>
```

I'm tying to get contents of some of the nodes(first node found) and put them in variables and then use regex replace using them in a different TXT file in efficient manner.
I'm trying something like

```
 XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(@"D:\MyFiles\1235-12-3053\230\124\124.xml",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                var s=from a in doc.Descendants("surname")
                    select a.First();
                var l=from x in doc.Descendants("label")
                    select x.First();
            ... so on
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\text.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Desktop\text.txt"), @"<a>[^<]+</a>", @"<a>s</a>"));
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\text.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Desktop\text.txt"), @"<b>[^<]+</b>", @"<b>l</b>"));
    ... so on
```

But `First()` method is giving an error, and also using `WriteAllText` many times, is that a good practice? Can I do multiple replaces in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading and saving the file to the hard drive multiple times, you should consider loading the text to a variable (string).

When i memory you can use regex to search and replace for multiple different patterns as you wish, and when completely done save the file.

Comment: You need to specify more information about it. What error do you get?

Comment: i'm getting an error message `'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: If you want to use the extension method `First`, you have to reference to `System.Linq`. It seems like you haven't done it like this: `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: If you still get the same error when writing: `doc.Descendants("surname").First()` you are not using `System.Linq` properly, which is NOT the same as `System.Xml.Linq`.

Comment: could you mind showing some code, I'm getting confused...I do have both `using System.Linq; using System.Xml.Linq;` in my code, I cant figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(file,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
    var s=(from a in doc.Descendants("surname")
     select a).First().Value;
    var l=(from x in doc.Descendants("label")
     select x).First().Value;
 string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            text = Regex.Replace(text,  @"<a>[^<]+</a>", @"<a>"+s+@"</a>");
            text = Regex.Replace(text,  @"<b>[^<]+</b>", @"<b>"+l+@"</b>");
            File.WriteAllText(file, text);
```

This should do if I understand correctly what you wanted from this program.

There is also a method called `UpdateText` I believe, to do the updating of the file but I'm not that familiar with it...maybe someone else can help you on that method.